# Selenium not clicking

Tags: python-3.x, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm making a script for a cookieclickerbot with selenium chromedriver. 
The problem is that it neither is clicking the cookie nor upgrading. 
I've been playing around with the code for about two days, but I'm not that experienced with classes. 
Please test it out and see if you can solve it and don't worry about arranging the classes differently I just want to see what I've done wrong. 
Hoppefully you can also explain it too me so I can learn more about selenium, python and classes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
class COOKIEBOT2000(object):

    def __init__(self,upgrade=1,click=1,prints=1):
        self.upgrade = upgrade
        self.click = click
        self.prints = prints
        self.cursor = 0
        self.grandma = 0
        self.farm = 0
        self.mine = 0
        self.factory = 0
        self.temple = 0
        self.wizard = 0
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome ("Path too chromedriver")
    def Clicker(self):
        try:
            if self.click == 1:
                if self.prints == 1:
                    print ("clicking")
                    print(self.driver)
                i = 0
                while i < 11:
                    click = driver.find_element_by_id("bigCookie")
                    click.click()
                    i = i + 1
                    print (i)
                if self.prints == 1:
                        click = driver.find_element_by_id("cookies")
                        click.click()
                        click = click.text
                        money = click.split("\n")
                        money = money[0].split(" ")
                        money = int(money[0])
                        print (money)
                self.Upgrader()
        except:
            self.Upgrader()
    def Upgrader(self):
        if self.upgrade == 1:
            if self.prints == 1:
                print ("Upgrading")
            try:
                click = driver.self.find_element_by_id("product0")
                if click.get_attribute("class") == "product unlocked enabled":
                    if self.cursor < 51:
                            click.click()
                            self.cursor = self.cursor + 1
                click = driver.self.find_element_by_id("product1")
                if click.get_attribute("class") == "product unlocked enabled":
                    if self.grandma < 7:
                            click.click()
                            self.grandma = self.grandma + 1
                click = driver.self.find_element_by_id("product2")
                if click.get_attribute("class") == "product unlocked enabled":
                    if self.farm < 41:
                            click.click()
                            self.farm = self.farm + 1
                click = driver.self.find_element_by_id("product3")
                if click.get_attribute("class") == "product unlocked enabled":
                    if self.mine < 41:
                            click.click()
                            self.mine = self.mine + 1
                click = driver.self.find_element_by_id("product4")
                if click.get_attribute("class") == "product unlocked enabled":
                    if self.factory < 51:
                            click.click()
                            self.factory = self.factory + 1
                click = driver.self.find_element_by_id("product5")
                if click.get_attribute("class") == "product unlocked enabled":
                    if self.temple < 51:
                            click.click()
                            self.temple = self.temple + 1
                click = driver.self.find_element_by_id("product6")
                if click.get_attribute("class") == "product unlocked enabled":
                    if self.wizard < 51:
                            click.click()
                            self.wizard = self.wizard + 1
                self.Clicker()
            except:
                self.Clicker()
                return
    def Start(self):
        self.driver.get("http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")
        sleep(1)
        if self.prints == 1:
            print("begun")
        self.Clicker()
CK = COOKIEBOT2000()
CK.Start()
```

Comment: Which click is not happening?

Comment: All of them are not happening, but I think that Shivan Mishra might have solved it. I’ll check when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be a silly mistake on your part that in your `Clicker` function, replace every instance of this-

```
driver.find_element_by_id
```

by this-

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id
```

And then, in your `Upgrader` function, replace every instance of this-

```
driver.self.find_element_by_id
```

by this -

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id
```

Doing that will make the script perform all the clicks continuously as the part of your game.

Comment: Did you test the script? Because then I can mark it as a solution now!

Comment: @Mr.Blue yes I have tested the script with the mentioned changes. It runs continuously without any errors.